# Map + 3DVenue as File for Offline use

Tags: android, here-api

Is there a way to use HereMaps completely offline, without ever going online and downloading a map or a venue? For example can i put a Here-Map or/and a 3DVenue-File in the asset folder and Load it on Activity start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible. We do not support deployment like that.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer!